# NEO4J Query for finding movies title with no tagline?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This query returns the Movie Matrix.

```
MATCH (tag {tagline: 'Welcome to the Real World'}) RETURN tag.title
```

but I want to return the title of all movies with no tagline

```
MATCH (notag {tagline: '**null**'}) RETURN notag.title
```

But the result shows nothing when the database had multiple movies with no tagline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` to find nodes where an attribute exists. If you negate it then you can find nodes where an attribute does not exist. `null` attributes are not present in Neo4j.

```
MATCH (notag:Movie) 
WHERE NOT exists(notag.tagline)
RETURN notag.title
```

Comment: It is less idiomatic, but it's possible to check if a property is null: `MATCH (notag:Movie) WHERE notag.tagline IS NULL RETURN notag.title` returns the same results.

Comment: absolutely true Gabor